# Redis modeling for sorting strings by count

Tags: redis

I have been storing and incrementing download counters like this:

```
INCRBY downloads:<filename> 1
```

But now I want to get downloads:* sorted by value so I can display a top downloads list.

I get the feeling I can probably store this better. I fooled around with:

```
ZINCRBY downloads 1 <filename>
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE downloads +inf -inf
```

Which does seem to give me the sorted list I want (most downloads to least) but it only returns the `<filename>`. It appears I would have to query the counts separately.

Basically, in SQL terms, if i may:

```
select filename, count(*) from downloads
```

How can I structure my Redis data to make that query possible/easy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the top films with `ZREVRANGE z 0 -1 WITHSCORES` instead, that will also return the scores.

Also this allows you to easily to get the "TOP N" films using "N-1" instead of "-1" in the above command.

Comment: Answer in 3 minutes from the creator of the project?! Now that's service. Thanks for Redis :) Works great BTW but I have to wait 8 minutes to accept the answer.